Using and changing a variable name for a value in a dict
I've encountered a challenge in doing repeated simulations with a changing parameter value using Python.  I'm looking for a clean way to change the parameter value.
Reducing it to the simplest case, we can assume the parameter is showing up as the value for some specific keys in a dictionary, D, let's say D[1] and D[2] are both delta.  I need to rerun the code with a changed value of delta, but updating D in practice is not as simple in my real context as updating D[1] and D[2]:
Here's the question:
Is there a way to create a dict D with some values equal to a parameter delta so that if I change delta later, the corresponding values in D are automatically updated?  Basically I'm sort of trying to set the value of D to be passed by reference.

More context:
Right now I have something like:
delta = 1
D = {1:delta, 2:delta, 3:1}  #the real process of creating `D` is computationally slow.
#... some arbitrary code here, some of which I can't modify that needs D[1] to behave like a number.

delta = 2
D = {1:delta, 2:delta, 3:1} 
#... equivalent code here

I can't really wrap this in a for loop because I'm actually doing this in a Jupyter notebook and I want to include a markdown cell describing the outputs each time I change delta.  Also creating D is pretty involved.
My best solution right now is to track which keys correspond to delta in a separate list and then go through and update all of them.  This process will be a touch messy and might cause confusion for some users who will not be all that familiar with python.
I don't think it is possible to do what I'm asking, but if so it would make my life much easier.

Why don't you define a class and use the objects of this class as the key values?

@StasSimonov So the issue is that really, I'm using networkx and I'm assigning some edge weights to be a parameter beta.  This is then fed into an algorithm which requires the edge weight to be a number.   I would like to change the value of beta for all edges whose weith is beta (other edges have weight delta or gamma).   So basically I'm looking for something where a reference to a parameter automatically gives the current value of the parameter.

A dataclass might do the trick. You can replace delta with an instance of a single-field dataclass, then fill your dictionary with references to that instance. Your example could be converted to something like this:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class dict_value:
    value: int

delta = dict_value(1)
D = {1:delta, 2:delta, 3:dict_value(1)}
print(D) # {1: dict_value(value=1), 2: dict_value(value=1), 3: dict_value(value=1)}

delta.value = 2
print(D) # {1: dict_value(value=2), 2: dict_value(value=2), 3: dict_value(value=1)}

